# How to restore database from dump or sql file in docker using volume?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am trying to run my database in docker which already have some data into it, But when I run it in docker it gives empty .. So how to restore my database in docker PostgreSQL image.

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear on how you start your docker container? By default the postgresql container will store it's data in the container itself. if you delete it and restart the container, all data will be gone. 
Try looking into mounting a volume into a docker container: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: I have dump as well as sql file of database, how can i restore in docker db.FYI, I am running docker on windows Machine.

Comment: Maybe also show the `docker run command` that you used to launch the container

Answer (score 42, accepted):

First, Start your docker posgtres container. Then execute the following command:

`docker exec -i <CONTAINER> psql -U <USER> -d <DB-NAME> < <PATH-TO-DUMP>`

- `<CONTAINER>` : Container ID or container name
- `<USER>` : User of PostgreSQL DBMS. If you use the standard postgres image with no specific config the user is `postgres`
- `<DB-NAME>`: The name of the DB. This DB should already exist. You can create a db when running your postgres container by specifying an environment variable named `POSTGRES_DB`
- `<PATH-TO-DUMP>`: Specify here the path to your dump file

**Example:**
`docker exec -i mypostgres psql -U postgres -d mydb < backup.sql`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am getting this error:-OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"-U\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Comment: Please give more detail in your original post. Tell us all the steps you took right from the beginning. It is very hard to help with so little information.

Comment: Hey... Thank you so much. Your command worked for me. It was my typo mistake. Silly me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ieggel The first line is missing the `psql` command between `<CONTAINER>` and `-U`, that's why it failed for Yesha Dave

Comment: Everyone says `docker exec -i <CONTAINER> psql -U <USER> -d <DB-NAME> < <PATH-TO-DUMP>` but if it is a dump from pg_dumpall, then it contains multiple dbs. Can -d be omitted in that case?